# ssh shared key between sudo accounts

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, ssh-keys

Okay, here is my situation:

- user A has personal account on server X & Y
- user A logs into server X with personal account
- user A sudo's into "escalated" account that has a shared key set up with another "escalated" account on server Y. Works without issue.
- user B ONLY has personal account on server X
- user B sudo's into same "escalated" account on server X but CANNOT ssh to server Y "escalated" account even though the shared key exists.

Does ssh rely on 'actual' user id (not sudo'd) for shared key to work?  My guess is that user B can't ssh without password because they do not have a personal account on both server X & Y.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sudo will use the current user key. Use the `ssh` switch `-i` to manually select the appropriate identity key for logging into server Y.

Comment: No. Running `sudo` will change the user and therefore use the key that has the target user (if there is one).